# How effective is elevated concrete for insulating moisture?

Tags: concrete, basement, boiler, moisture

I am replacing a boiler in my basement and the contractor told me it will be better for the new boiler if he build an elevated concrete platform on which the new boiler will sit.  He says this will reduce the moisture to the new boiler, does this make sense to any of you?  My thinking is, since this elevated concrete platform is connected/sitting on the basement floor which is also concrete, doesn't the moisture travels up this platform as well, and even if this elevated platform is higher than the concrete floor, the effectiveness of insulating moisture is sabotages by the connection which the platform and the ground shares?  Thanks for any valuable input.

Comment: Did he say whether he was concerned about wicking or flooding?

Comment: Hi bib, he didn't say, the property is on a hill so there shouldn't be flooding.  So it should be wicking.